# Running a C++ program from an m.file

Tags: matlab

For a project I am working on I'm preparing data in MATLAB, then running the data through a separate external application (written in C++) named `Model v2.exe`, then performing further analysis with the output in MATLAB. I'm trying to create an M-file which does all of this, but I am struggling to get the C++ program to launch from my MATLAB code.

How can I launch an external application from within my MATLAB code?

Comment: Just guessing: if the external C++ application is yours as well, you could also build it as a shared library and call it directly from matlab. This would have much less overhead than issuing a `system()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either make use of the `!` operator, or the `system()` command.

First, rename you application to something that has no spaces in the name, like `modelv2.exe`. Next, either make sure it is in the system path, as defined by your system environment variables, or generate a full path to it (eg: `C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\modelv2.exe`).

You can call an executable program from the command line using the exclamation point or the system command:

```
!modelv2
```

or:

```
!C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\modelv2.exe
```

will cause Windows to execute the program hello.exe if there is such a file in the current directory or on the system path. Alternatively:

```
system('modelv2');
```

or

```
system('C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\modelv2.exe');
```

will do the same thing.

**References**

---

1. "MATLAB Central - call and run an external program in matlab under windows", Accessed 2014-03-19, [`<http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/11568-call-and-run-an-external-program-in-matlab-under-windows>`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/11568-call-and-run-an-external-program-in-matlab-under-windows)

Comment: Thanks Dogbert, great help.

Comment: What happens if the external program needs an input parameter? How is it done, then?