# Launch C++ program from MATLAB script using MATLAB variables as arguments

Tags: c++, matlab

I know I can launch a executable in MATLAB with the `!example.exe` command or `system(example.exe)` as laid out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22514072/running-a-c-program-from-an-m-file). However, when I want to pass arguments to the C++ program, anything I type is taken as a string. How can I use MATLAB variables?

For example, let's say `example.exe` was the following program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    std::cout << argv[1] << std::endl;      
}
```

When I call it from MATLAB as `!example.exe hi`, I get the output `hi`.

But what if my MATLAB script were actually:

```
hi = 'HELLO!';
!example.exe hi
```

My output is still `hi`, but I want it to be `HELLO!`.

How do I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a string using your variables and then run it using [`eval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html). For example:

```
n = 3;
command = sprintf('!example.exe %i', n);
eval(command)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; this works, but can you (or anyone) comment on `system()` vs. `eval()`? What's the difference/what is the preferred function?

Comment: @marcman `eval()` can run any Matlab command. `system()` is specifically for shelling out to the OS. In your case I don't think it matters which one you use.

Comment: It's usually better to [avoid `eval`](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/)

Comment: @LuisMendo Good link! In general I agree, but in this case the only alternative is `system()` which isn't any better. (Okay, maybe a _tiny_ bit more efficient, but I bet you can't notice or measure the difference.)

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this is what you are looking for, but you can put the execution command together in a string using `sprintf` and then pass that to system. Something like:

```
hi = 'Hello!';
command = sprintf('example.exe %s', hi);
system(command);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use string concatenation:

```
hi = 'HELLO!';
system(['example.exe ' hi]);
```